# how to convert numeric column to factor in R

Tags: r, numeric, r-factor

I'm trying to use the `softImpute` command (from the `softImpute` package) for filling in missing values, and I'm trying to turn categorical variables in a large data frame into factor type before using the `softImpute`.

I've used `as.factor` command and `factor` command but they all yield the following

```
train[a]=factor(train[a])

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

`a` here is a vector like: `c(1:92)`

I tried `as.character` too but the `softImpute` command would not recognize the variables as character and would treat them as numeric, resulting in decimal values for categorical/indicator variables.

Comment: Are you looking for like this: x <- factor(x), where x <- c(1:92). Output format will help us more.

Comment: No, I'm trying to turn 1st to 92st column in the data frame "train" into factors, because they are categorical variables.

Comment: What's the complete code which you have written?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
train[[a]]=factor(train[[a]])
```

This does assume, of course that `,a` is an object with either a numerical value in the range  `1:length(train)` or is one of the values in the `names(train)` vector. If you reference a dataframe using "[" you get a list with one element which happens to be the vector you were hoping to "factorize" but it isn't really a vector but is rather a one element list. The "[[" function instead gives you just the vector.

Comment: I get the following error:Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2.

Comment: a is a numerical value in the range. The structure of a is integer and a is a vector of certain numbers. I'm trying to select the ith, jth, and etc. columns in the train data frame and turn them into factors.

Comment: So you want individual elements to be listed as factors? Is my understanding correct.

Comment: Yes. I searched the site and used train[,a] <- lapply(train[,a] , factor) and this worked! Thank you for your refs.